# Change color of button in UIWebView ios objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

We have loaded the login page in webview, now once user clicks on "login" button in webview, i want to change the color of that button using iOS objective - c code. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: is the button created in IB?

Comment: No, its a web page element

Comment: if the button wasn't created by you, and its loading from another source, how could you possibly change the colour?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using UIWebView's delegate method.
Then you can execute JavaScript code in ObjC or Swift.

I will show you the  detail code after few minutes because I'm on the way home.

---

Hi, I'm back.

The major thoughts is that reassign the button's `onclick` property.
Call the old `onclick' function when implementing the new function.

First of all, you should know the button's `onclick` function.
By reading the web page's source code, you can know the function's name.

You need to know the button's id, too.

For example, the the `clickButton()` is the function name. The `btn` is the button's id.

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Test Button" onclick="clickButton()">
```

And then, you should launch your Xcode and write a UIWebView to load the web page.
You should implement the `delegate` property and override the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {  
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () { document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor = 'red'; clickButton(); }"];
}
```

You should replace the `'red'` and `'btn'` with the right code.

Answer (score 0):

I read this somewhere...It works for me..

hit this link:  http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/Bvd9d/ and Place JS Code in your JS File.Import it in .HTML file.

Try this code:

```
function highlight(colour) {
var range, sel;
if (window.getSelection) {

    try {
        if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8 case
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}}
```

For Objective C :

Call this method:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"highlight('#ff0')"];
```